# sssd caching user credentials even the cache_credentials is set to false

Tags: ssh, rhel, authentication, active-directory, sssd

I have setup Redhat host to authenticate AD users for `ssh` sessions. Everything is working as expected, however, single concern, user credentials are being cached somewhere.

Upon **first time login** using `ssh`, user is asked to enter the password however, later on (second third attempts etc), whenever user initiates the ssh connection, `ssh connection` is established without even prompting to enter the password. This could be a security risk.

**How can I prevent caching the credentials** and have the user enter password each time when they want to connect to the RHEL server.

> /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

```
[nss]
filter_groups = root
filter_users = root
reconnection_retries = 3

[pam]
reconnection_retries = 3

[domain/example.com]
ad_domain = example.com
krb5_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-samba
cache_credentials = false
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = True
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
access_provider = simple
simple_allow_groups = Domain Admins
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue, SSH Sessions Credentials were being cached in my terminal. `MobaX freeware` was being used with `"save password"` defaults to `yes`. Cleared the password vault.

```
  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not SSSD caching credentials, but SSH either logging you with GSSAPI or with public key. Even when SSSD caches credentials, it always prompts you for the password.